# How to overlap a view over other with three Views in android?

Tags: android, layout, view, overlap

I have an issue : this issue could be understood by following example.

The screen uses three views lets say A,B,C. A is set for Drag and drop on B. What I want is when A is being dragged to B , A should overlap C view but B should overlap A.This makes it three layers B on top,A in middle and C lowest layer.

I dont know how to do this ,with two views it could be implemented but with three how can I solve this Problem.

If anyone cant understand my problem please let me know?Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem :

Used bringToFront() method in the same sequence I want the views

```
       A.bringToFront();
       B.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using "Relative Layout"

Comment: yes I know that but how? I am using drag and drop on view in middle.

Comment: i can do it easily using drag and drop... but it suppose to in your xml file "Relative layout should be root layout (mean this layout has no parent layout )... OR you can also do that using properties...

Comment: I have used relative layout but how would i do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add views dynamically.Try this.

```
   RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_id);

   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setText("Button Name"); // Similarly set different property for the button.
```

Finally you have to add this button to the respective layout.

```
   rLayout.addView(btn);
```